# Is it possible to add and initialize a column in a single query?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Is it possible to add a column to a table and set it to a particular value for all existing records in a single query?

Obviously it can be done in two queries:

```
alter table Blah add column NewBlah int;
update Blah set NewBlah = 1;
```

Is it possible to combine those into a single query in SQLite?

Comment: put a default value into the alter table. Since the columns are newly created they couldn't possibly have a previous value, and will get the default instead.

Comment: Why do you think that you need to do this in a single query?

Comment: I don't _need_ to do it, but it would be cleaner to be able to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a default value to add in this column

```
alter table Blah add column NewBlah int default 1;
```

Comment: That will populate the column but has slightly different semantics, as any rows added in the future will still have a default value of 1 for that column instead of no default value.